# How to compile code with std::reduce and #include <execution_policy> using g++6?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

Can somebody tell me how to compile example code for `std::reduce`, which is on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <execution_policy>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> v(10'000'007, 0.5);

    {
        auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        double result = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0);
        auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> ms = t2 - t1;
        std::cout << std::fixed << "std::accumulate result " << result
                  << " took " << ms.count() << " ms\n";
    }

    {
        auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        double result = std::reduce(std::par, v.begin(), v.end());
        auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> ms = t2 - t1;
        std::cout << "std::reduce result "
                  << result << " took " << ms.count() << " ms\n";
    }
}
```

I am working under Mint18 with fresh g++6.2 installed. During compilation I use only `-std=c++17` flag. What should I do if I want to use `execution_policy` (`#include <execution_policy>`)? Currently my compiler tells me that `reduce` is not a member of namespace `std` and that there is no such file as `execution_policy`.

Comment: Most library vendors haven't yet implemented many C++17 features. You'll have to wait not too long.

Comment: While you're waiting for libstdc++ to catch up, there's already [HPX](http://stellar-group.org/libraries/hpx/).

Comment: @ildjarn that's what I used when I wrote that example (and then posted the way it *should* look in C++.. now edited to match current draft)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither libstdc++ (used by default with g++) nor libc++ (use by default with clang) have implemented execution_policy support yet.

Progress towards implementing new features in libstdc++ is tracked on [this page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.201z).  libc++ progress is tracked [here](http://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1z_status.html).  As you can see, P0024R2 "The Parallelism TS Should be Standardized" has not yet been implemented by either library as of time of writing.